# Express Handlebars getting first letter of every string

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Some discord servers don't have icons, and discord renders the icons as the first char of each word in the guilds name. I am trying to do that in handlebars with express. I did the following, but it errored.

```html
<h1>Welcome, {{username}}!</h1>
<ul>
<h2>Your guilds</h2>
{{#each guilds as |key value|}}
    <li>
        {{#if key.icon}}
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/{{key.id}}/{{key.icon}}?size=64" alt="profile"> </p>{{key.name}}</p>
            {{else}}
            <div>
                <h3>{{ key.name.match(/\b\w/g).join('') }}</h3>
                <p>{{key.name}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Error

```
Error: Parse error on line 10:
...    <h3>{{ key.name.match(/\b\w/g).join(
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Handlebars, you can work with custom helpers functions that handle javascript logic outside the templates. You should make two changes in your project to achieve that:

1. create a file with custom helpers, normally inside `helpers` folder in your project:

**./helpers/hbs.js**

```js
function getFirstLetter(name) {
  return name.match(/\b\w/g).join("");
}

module.exports = { getFirstLetter };
```

2. Modify handlebars middleware configuration in the `app.js` to use custom helpers created by you:

**./app.js**

```js
/**
 * Import Handlebars
 */
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
/**
 * Import Custom Helpers
 */
const hbs = require("./helpers/hbs");
/**
 * Template Engine
 */
app.engine(
  ".hbs",
  exphbs({
    ... all configuration here...
    helpers: hbs, // add custom helpers.
  })
);
```

Now you can use custom helper inside your template like this:

```
<h1>Welcome, {{username}}!</h1>
<ul>
<h2>Your guilds</h2>
{{#each guilds as |key value|}}
    <li>
        {{#if key.icon}}
        <img src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/{{key.id}}/{{key.icon}}?size=64" alt="profile"> </p>{{key.name}}</p>
            {{else}}
            <div>
                <h3>{{getFirstLetter key.name}}</h3>
                <p>{{key.name}}</p>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: The `name.match(/\b\w/g).join("");` regex looks daunting and would throw an error if `name` were an empty string. I think something like `(name || '')[0]` is more expressive and easier to understand.